# Is it possible to use a union member as object storage?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, storage, unions, placement-new

I wonder whether we can use a `union` member as storage for an explicitly initialized and destructed object, such as in the following code:

```
struct X
{
    X() { std::cout << "C"; }
    ~X() { std::cout << "D"; }
};

struct X_owner
{
    union
    {
        X x;  // storage for owned object
    };

    X_owner()
    {
        new (&x) X{};
    }

    ~X_owner()
    {
        (&x)->~X();
    }
};

int main()
{
    X_owner xo;
}
```

The printed output is as expected only `CD`. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/M1Gov4o4d

The question is motivated by a programming assignment, where students were supposed to explicitly define storage for an object. The expected solution was a suitably aligned and sized buffer of type `unsigned char` or `std::byte`, or `std::aligned_storege`. However, few of them used `union` this way within their solutions. And I am not sure whether this is correct, though I cannot find anything wrong about it.

Note: For the sake of simplicity, I do not care about copy/move semantics in this example.

Comment: I think that `(&x)->~X();` requires [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed valid.

> **[class.base.init]**
>
> [9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.base.init#9) In a non-delegating constructor, if a given potentially constructed subobject is not designated by a *mem-initializer-id* (including the case where there is no *mem-initializer-list* because the constructor has no *ctor-initializer*), then
>
> - [...]
> - otherwise, if the entity is an anonymous union or a variant member ([class.union.anon]), no initialization is performed;
> - [...]

So `x` is not initialized, and so is not within its lifetime until one explicitly does something with that lump of storage to create an object there. The placement new isn't even replacing an object in that storage, there was non there until the new expression. So we aren't even delving into places where `std::launder` may be required.

Seems like an acceptable approach for doing it.

Comment: Is `(&x)->~X();` pedantically correct (may that depend of standard)? Even if `new (&x) X{}` and `&x` are same pointer, not sure we can use directly `x` after the placement new (without `std::launder`).

Comment: _`x` is not initialized, and so is not within its lifetime_ ... _The placement new isn't even replacing an object in that storage, there was non there_ So, `x` denotes an object which is not within lifetime or there is no object?

Comment: _we aren't even delving into places where `std::launder` may be required_ Formally reading, if a name didn't denote an object within lifetime before replacement, the name won't rebind to the new one (so `std::launder` is required).

Answer (score 1):

The shown code is correct. To be functionally complete, a copy constructor and an assignment operator should be formally defined. Things become complicated, very quickly, if the `union` were to hold another object. To remain valid the wrapper object will need to explicitly track which underlying object is constructed, in the union, and handle these matters by itself.

But, if things were to go in that direction you can just let [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) deal with it.